# Inertia again: significant figures

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi.

I'm facing really bad bugs which seem to be related to inertia. I'm trying to understand the issue with Gazebo and found that the inertia tensors are [0] for the smaller parts:

[image: image description]

This is consistent with my bugs, since with the large arm parts, it works more or less, but with the gripper, that becomes crazy. The small parts of the arm and the gripper have 1e-4 values for the inertia tensor.

Here is a short video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3T2s96NkvFI

The joint 3 is moved to 1.0 rad, the next links should stay in line (at 0 rad), but they don't. If you stay long enough (several tenth of second), they finally go to there stable position.

So I wonder how many figures are considered in Gazebo. What are the best practice for simulating this kind of robot? (we could imagine to use a simple kinematic simulation for this part of the body, as they have a low contribution to the overall behavior)

Any inputs will be helpful.

This question is related to:

http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4372/the-inertia-matrix-explained/

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4594/inertia-again:-significant-figures/) by [Arn-O](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/416/arn-o/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 316 on 2013-10-06

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-10-06**:
Can you please describe the bugs.

**Comment by [Arn-O](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/416/arn-o/) on 2013-10-06**:
YouTube video included in the text. It looks like the upper part of the arm has a very huge inertia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The main bug was due to the inertia of the fingers:

```
  <inertial>
    <mass value="${finger_right_link_mass}"/>
    <inertia ixx="0.00001" ixy="0.000" ixz="0.000" iyy="0.00001" iyz="0.00001" izz="0.00001"/>
  </inertial>
```

I changed the values to 0.0001 (x10) and the behavior is far more realistic. So i guess that there is some kind of limit there.

---

Originally posted by [Arn-O](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/416/arn-o/) with karma: 316 on 2013-10-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-10-09**:
If inertia values are too small, especially when connected to links that have a much large inertia, then simulation will have unexpected results. I think you found a good solution to your problem.

**Comment by [Arn-O](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/416/arn-o/) on 2013-10-11**:
Thx Nate. Is there a rule for "too small"? Is it possible to cancel this effect, since the overall contribution of the finger inertia is probably negligible?

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-10-11**:
A good rule is to make connected links have less than one order of magnitude difference in their intertias.